# How do I automatically populate a select box in html using jquery & ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my HTML code (which is i think where the problem is):

```
<form name="County" method= "post" action="post">
<select id= item.county_name name= item.county_name> 
<option value="item.county_name"> County </option>

</select>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://107.170.75.124/courts/courts.json',
method: 'post'
})
.done (function(data){
   data.forEach(function(item){
    console.log (item.county_name);
     $ ('select'). append ('<option value="' + item.county_name + '">' + 
'</option>');


})
});
```

When I attempt to run it the drop box shows all 100 areas where they should be a county, but they are blank. So my guess is that there is something wrong with the HTML preventing it from being visible. All of the counties show up in my console

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting to supply the actual display value of the `<option>` elements. Your `<option>` elements are winding up like this:

```
<option value='ajax result item here'></option>
```

With the `<option>` element being empty.

Change the line to this:

```
 $ ('select').append('<option value="' + 
     item.county_name + '">' + item.county_name + '</option>');
```

Or, just this (because when no value is explicitly set on an `option`, the value becomes the displayed text of the `option`):

```
 $ ('select').append('<option>' + item.county_name + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"value"` param just sets the value of the option, but not it's label. The label needs to be between the `<option>`tags

Your code is incomplete.

```
$ ('select').append('<option value="' + item.county_name + '">' + '</option>');
```

results in something like this

```
<option value="somecountry"></option>
```

You need to change it like:

```
$ ('select').append ('<option value="' + item.county_name + '">' + item.county_name + '</option>');
```

which should output

```
<option value="somecountry">somecountry</option>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your suggested code fix. Once you fix that, you will have the same code that I posted an hour and a half earlier.